# Trying to make a dictionary of words using key as all the possible lengths

Tags: python

I have very beginner level knowledge of python programming. I am doing this little challenge where I need to make a dictionary of words using all the possible lengths of words as keys and all the words of that length as values.

So for example it should look sort of like this:

{2: [no,is,as,....]}

I have this code and I am getting a keyerror pointing to line 4 of the second cell of this code. I am using jupyter notebooks and so I have done my best showing the different cells by using underscores below.

```
def bigword(wordclean):
    return [max(len(word) for word in wordclean)]

listwords = {}
x = bigword(wordclean)[0]
for i in range (1 , x + 1):
   listwords[i].append([word for word in wordclean if len(word)== i])
```

I understand its referring to a key does not exist kind of an error meaning its can not append to a key that does not exist. How would I fix this? Would I need to use dict from collections or is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: The posted code, if it isn't rejected for indentation errors, will `return` before it ever initializes `listwords`.

Comment: Please check your indentation, I'm _guessing_ the lines starting with `listwords` are not meant to be part of the function, but it's impossible to tell. If that is indeed the case, you need to create the keys before trying to append values to them, use `dict.update` instead of `dict[key].append`, or use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: I actually tried to put underscores to make a distinction between the two pieces of code but I believe someone edited it.

The piece of code starting from listwords = {} is indeed meant to be in another cell.

I had to edit the indentation because without them the preview would not show my code

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to append to a key that does not exist. use a `defaultdict`. something like

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

for word in words:
   result[len(word)].append(word)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking that was the case.